# Eclipse color highlighting broken

Tags: eclipse, themes

I have an Eclipse theme installed through the color themes plugin. After solving some known issues, it does happen that sometimes the color highlighting breaks after a change in the code. For example:

[image]

Once this happens, I need to restart Eclipse. I have tested and it happens with at least some of the themes.
Is this happening to anybody else? I cannot find anything on the Internet about this specific issue.

Comment: Do you have any error displayed in `Error Log View` ? Or in `workspace/.metadata/.log` ? You can also check if this is a known issue on the github page : https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-color-theme/issues

Comment: Well, that log has 8500 lines (key bindings just broke as well). Is there anything specific I should look for there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, finally, I found the answer, or at least a workaround to it.

The problem was that the source files were not properly openn by Eclipse. Even if they are in the workspace (set up through CMake), it is not OK to drag the files into the IDE. They have to be open from the project explorer.